# Rails migration not seeming to work? Accidentally named a column "type", ran a migration but receiving error

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I accidentally named a column in my Item model "type" and I wrote a migration to rename it.

```
class RenameTypeToTagged < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_column :items, :type, :tagged
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

When I restart the server, and rake db:migrate it still spits back "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type". I've renamed the attr_accesible in the Item model by hand but it doesn't seem to resolve. any ideas? thanks

Comment: You haven't updated your forms, because they're still submitting the old value.

Comment: hmm. I have changed f.label and f.text_field both to :tagged, but it's still not working. Is there anywhere else in the app I need to change?

Comment: If you look in the log file, at the point where the request hits the server, you can see the list of parameters. Do you see 'tagged' or 'type' in the list?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it can help, but you have the possibility to rollback to a previous version of the migration. you can after redo a new migration file with the right field name.

to rollback to a previous migration, if your migration file with the error is named :

```
20130629033812_create_items.rb
```

you just have to type

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20130629033812
```